# How to Avoid a Distorted Android Camera Preview With ZXing.Net.Mobile in xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am Applying `ZXing.Net.Mobile` for barcode scan and when I run the application I get stretched 
camera preview.

my code looks like...

```
<Grid>

            <forms:ZXingScannerView x:Name="_scanView" OnScanResult="_scanView_OnOnScanResult" IsScanning="true"
                                    HeightRequest="300" 
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    />
</Grid>
```

How can I avoid this?

**Update**

I tried https://laptrinhx.com/how-to-avoid-a-distorted-android-camera-preview-with-zxing-net-mobile-4270557032/

*interface*

```
public interface IZXingHelper
    {
        MobileBarcodeScanningOptions.CameraResolutionSelectorDelegate TestingDelegate { get; set; }
    }
```

*implementation in Android*

```
public class TestingResolution : IZXingHelper
    {
        public MobileBarcodeScanningOptions.CameraResolutionSelectorDelegate TestingDelegate { get; set; }

        public CameraResolution SelectLowestResolutionMatchingDisplayAspectRatio(List<CameraResolution> availableResolutions)
        {
            CameraResolution result = null;

            //a tolerance of 0.1 should not be recognizable for users
            double aspectTolerance = 0.1;

            //calculating our targetRatio
            var targetRatio = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
            var targetHeight = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
            var minDiff = double.MaxValue;

            //camera API lists all available resolutions from highest to lowest, perfect for us
            //making use of this sorting, following code runs some comparisons to select the lowest resolution that matches the screen aspect ratio
            //selecting the lowest makes QR detection actual faster most of the time
            foreach (var r in availableResolutions)
            {
                //if current ratio is bigger than our tolerance, move on
                //camera resolution is provided landscape ...
                //if (Math.Abs(((double)r.Width / r.Height) - targetRatio) > aspectTolerance)
                //    continue;
                //else
                if (Math.Abs(r.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
                    minDiff = Math.Abs(r.Height - targetHeight);
                result = r;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public TestingResolution()
        {
            List<CameraResolution> resolution = new List<CameraResolution>
            {
                new CameraResolution()
                {
                    Height = 200,
                    Width = 300
                }
            };

            TestingDelegate.Invoke(new List<CameraResolution> {SelectLowestResolutionMatchingDisplayAspectRatio(resolution)});
        }
    }
```

*implementation in mypage.xcml.cs class*

```
public PartialPagexaml()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE},
                CameraResolutionSelector = DependencyService.Get<IZXingHelper>().TestingDelegate
            };

            _scanView.Options = options;
        }
```

there I am getting `Target Invocation Error` in `my page.xaml.cs class`
in below line.

```
var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE},
                CameraResolutionSelector = DependencyService.Get<IZXingHelper>().TestingDelegate
            };
```

can I get a help to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you had used Grid . Don't forget to set the **Row** and **Column** .

For example , if you want to put the scan view in the center of the Grid .

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="0.33*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.33*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.33*" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <forms:ZXingScannerView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="_scanView" OnScanResult="_scanView_OnOnScanResult" IsScanning="true"

                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                />

</Grid>
```

If you do want to set the fix Height . Use StackLayout is better .

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <forms:ZXingScannerView  x:Name="_scanView" 
                                 OnScanResult="_scanView_OnOnScanResult" 
                                 IsScanning="true"
                                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                 HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="400"
                                    />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: actually I need to set a aspect ratio here, so you know a way to do it?

Comment: This is a very dangerous piece of code: It assumes that the aspect ratio of the preview frame is 4:3 because you set Width to 400 and Height to 300. ZXing determines the best matching preview frame resolution with an algorithm. Take into consideration that Android has a very diverse combination of screen resolutions and camera preview resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your code I guess you must add `WidthRequest = "300"`.

As you have just requested for the Height parameter, the height is set to "300" but you haven't mentioned for width parameter & you have set `VerticleOptions="CenterAndExpand"`so it will occupy the whole width of the screen giving you a stretch effect. You must specify `WidthRequest` according to your IU appearance.

Hint - Let the barcode scanner open in full screen as it is the standard way to use barcode scanning, you can remove `HeightRequest= "300"` from your code.

Comment: I want add a fix Height here, this is not going to open as Full screen. Do you know a way to set aspect ratio here?